# Repeat key after double press

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-accelerators

The following is **default behavior**:

- if I hold a key <kbd>X</kbd> for less then `t` milliseconds, the key <kbd>X</kbd> gets sent
- if I hold a key <kbd>X</kbd> for more then `t` milliseconds, the key <kbd>X</kbd> gets sent repeatedly with speed `v`,

where `t` and `v` can be set in the keyboard settings of Ubuntu (`Keyboard` -> `Repeat Keys` -> `Delay` and `Speed` for `t` and `v` respectively). Now I would like to **add the following behaviour**:

- if I hold a key <kbd>X</kbd> for less then `t` milliseconds and press the same key <kbd>X</kbd> again, the key <kbd>X</kbd> gets sent repeatedly with speed `v`.

**Does anybody know how to accomplish this?**

The **reason** for my desire for this behavior is speed: double tapping a key is much faster than waiting for the delay `t`.